# Filtering and searching in Foundry Slate app using Platform source

Tags: foundry-slate

I switched from using Phonograph2 queries to using Platform object sets as the data source for my POC app. This made displaying the basic table of data super easy, but I can't tell if this prevents me from using filters (including text search). Would I need to create a normal SQL or Phonograph2 query in order to add filter criteria for a widget? I could write a function to do the work, but that feels like more of a workaround.

Similarly I'm not seeing anywhere to configure the data source to use server paging and sorting. Is that something that I would need a query to do as well?

Answer (score 0):

I realized there's an option to add filters in the Object Set section of the platform tab. Documentation: https://pf.hdvi.com/workspace/documentation/product/slate/platform#object-set-filter-builder-mode

> To create an object set s_object_set1, you need to select the base object type and optionally add filters with AND/OR logic. The filter’s fields will account for the object’s property data type. For example, numeric properties will take a number range as the filter. You can further nest individual AND/OR filters in each filter level to limit the objects to specific results.
>
> You can also use Slate’s handlebars in the filter fields so that you can parameterize an object set based on a dynamically changing input.

Comment: Text search is still an unknown. Specifically fuzzy search for multiple properties...